# Using gray font, is it OK?

Tags: color, fonts, print-design, grayscale

I am writing a math draft in PDF format.

Is it OK to use gray font for the parts of math proofs I remove but retain?

If somebody print my PDF, will gray fonts work well with all modern printers?

Also which RGB value do you suggest for "grayed out" font?

Comment: This question is too broad for our Q&A format. Do you have an example of what you've tried? What are you printing on? Is there a background color? What's the convention in the math field? Why include these proofs at all?

Comment: The example is not yet published, but should be soon. I do not print, I use an on-screen reader; but I am afraid that others may print it on any possible media. Background is white paper (as in a book). There are no conventions. The question why to include the proofs is not suitable for this site, it is related with mathematics not with printing

Comment: Do you want them to be readable? Are any other colors used? What fonts are you using? How are the grayed out sections positioned relative to the other content?

Comment: Yes I want it to be readable. I use only black otherwise. I use vector version of Computer Modern fonts. They are positioned as a common part of a text (not positioned in a different way).

Comment: "I am afraid others may print it on any possible media. Background is white paper." --- this is an oxymoronic statement.

Comment: You say there are no conventions. How have your colleagues solved the issue? What is pushing you to use screened text? (There is no gray ink.) What other techniques have you considered and why are they undesirable? Is this an opportunity for you to be creative?

Comment: I don't remember any colleagues to solve this issue (maybe they use overstriken font). What is "screened text"? I considered stroken text, but it is even harder to read. No need for creativity in this, creativity should here be not in font but in text

Comment: *the parts of math proofs I remove but retain* – I fail to understand this. Please be more specific as to what you actually want to achieve. This strongly feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/255554).

Comment: I mean that I remove a part of the proof because it is replaced with another alternative better proof, but I want not to delete the old proof completely but allow to read it too, for these who want see alternative proofs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How best to emphasize a portion of your paper?

All printers can easily reproduce grey text. The issue with grey text is that of sufficient contrast to be legible and easily readable.

Legibility will be an issue where symbols are used. Mathematic is heavy with problematic situations.
Here's where you should look for them

- Superscripts
- Subscripts
- Limits (the little arrows and lemniscate)
- Integrals
- Italics for unknowns
- Small sizes of roman styles tend to lose their serifs
- Heavy contrast fonts—the thick/thin parts proportions

Readability will be an issue in the typeface you choose. Try the worst part of your manuscript to use a few different faces so that you can find one that reads well. Lucida is a large family to accommodate anything you need for styles, formats, and foreign language glyph and symbol support. Stone is another great face for you. OCR works well on either of them.

Make a sample. Do a little of what you propose to use on a single page as a PDF. Photocopy it without any adjustments on a public photocopier. The resulting copy will represent what you can expect your work will look like after you release it into the wild.

Critically evaluate the result. Make any adjustments you think necessary and re-test your sample, etc. When you get a satisfactory result, you have achieved a reasonable expectation of your work.

This is an opportunity to be creative and informative. Good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK to use gray font for the parts of math proofs I remove but
>   retain?

Not sure how a graphic designer could answer this.

> If somebody print my PDF, will gray fonts work well with all modern
>   printers?

Yes, generally speaking if you have enough contrast a printer will be fine printing gray colors.

> Also which RGB value do you suggest for "grayed out" font?

I don't believe there is any strict rule for this and the use of color for "grayed out" font depends on context. On the internet, a website can use a cursor mouse hover "not-allowed" or have text with a strike through it.

But colors that have enough distinction from being black and still readable could be:

50% Gray: RGB(125,125,125)

60% Gray: RGB(153,153,153), <- lighter

Using a gray brighter than 75%+ may be hard for some users to read on a white background.

---

If the font is a different color than B&W and you want a "grayed out" text look then you can use the HSB color model to change the base color.

Lower the saturation and increase the brightness value.